# cimg pixel value - numerical

Tags: c++, jpeg, cimg

is there a way to get the int value of a pixel returned with cimg? I'm in the process of building a basic ASCII art program that converts JPG's to character arrays, and I have the entire utility built out but I cann not find a way to get the unsigned char's converted into the range of ints I need (0-255, although the specifics don't matter so long as its a predictable interval).

Does anyone have any idea how to get a numerical pixel value from a JPG? (library suggestions or anything else are completely welcome)

Here is the pixel output:

```
\�_b��}�HaX�gNzԴ�����p��-�u�����lqu��Lߐ_"T������{�y�sricX[[TXgZ]`a~�t91960d�BpvJ0kY@uR!BpMWb\W?j"@���dCy2+4?ڽ�TT<Tght%P%y;mhͬ�����8#1�H��)����:4lu���CY|��u&<_��ī��������������ȿF�����LP:����N���-�Q�+�2;E3(�SdRO6��NI16j{#�0(( 
: pixel data
```

It's already been converted to black and white, so even accessing the numerical value of one color channel off the cimg would be fine. I just can't seem to get any kind of intelligible/manipulable output from the image, even though the image itself is exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

cast it as an int using (int)img(x,y) and ignore the extra channels